# Getting error as ChromeDriver exited with code: 1 in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, npm, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

When I am running the azure pipeline for regression any random test cases are getting failed due to this error "ChromeDriver exited with code: 1"

- My Chrome browser version is 117 & I have updated the driver as well to 117 version
- In Regression every time any random test cases are getting failed due to this error some are getting passed & some are getting failed due to this error
- When this error is throwing for the particular test case & when I am checking same in VM Browser itself is not getting launched[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vIgf.png)
- I have update the driver to 117 with this command "npm i chromedriver@117.0.0" still same issue is coming

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.